# how to avoid g++ linker error "undefined reference"

Tags: gcc, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

if function definition is not available and only the function prototype is externed in header files, then g++ compiler wont give any errors. but during linking, g++ linker will identify the error and says "undefined reference" to corresponding fn. i don't care abt fn definition. i just want to get the binary image and whenever corresponding fn called from that image, then that time only i want to crash. may i know the linker flags to suppress this "undefined reference" linker error?. In VC++, there is a options called /FORCE. is there any similar flags?

Comment: What do you expect to happen for undefined symbols which aren't functions?

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. It will be great if symbols other than functions shows the same weak symbol behaviour. but it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely undefined behaviour, but if you want a crash ...

If you have an undefined symbol such as a function `void h()` then its mangled name will be `_Z1hv`, so if you define a symbol that name and external linkage it will be found, even if the type is wrong:

```
int _Z1hv = 0;
void h();

int main()
{
  h();
}
```

This will link, but crash at run-time because the call to `h()` will try to "run" a function at the address of the integer variable.

Doing this is wrong and disgusting and kills kittens.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I thing, you understood my doubt in a wrong-way. i am looking for gcc/g++ linker flags to suppress the error "undefined reference".

Comment: You don't have a "doubt" you have a question. "Doubt" does not mean the same thing. Anyway, there is no such option for executables.

Comment: This is beautiful. And disgusting at the same time. Thank you :'D